# Setting cookie path to "/" does not make cookie accessible to entire site

Tags: php, cookies

Why when set php cookie path to "/" doesn't work for every subdirs in the domain, but just for the current directory.

cookie is set like:

```
setcookie("name", "val", expire_time, "/");
```

It just doesn't want to work.

Comment: This is older than dirt, but you may have had a duplicate cookie set for your subdirectory. A cookie set for your current path is going to override a cookie with the same name set at the base path.

Answer (score 29):

try including the domain parameter:

```
setcookie("name", "val", expire_time, "/", ".domain.com");
// don't forget the prefixing period: .domain.com
```

that will enable all sudomains of "domain.com"

Comment: The question did not ask about subdomain, rather sub directories.

Answer (score 24):

Are you testing on localhost? In that case, you need to pass null as the value for `$domain`.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me sort it out for my localhost installation

Answer (score 8):

Setting the cookie path to `/` should make it available to the entire domain. If you set your cookie like that, and it isn't being sent, there is something else wrong.

Try using the Web Developer addon in Firefox. It shows you details on the available cookies. Maybe that can help you diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party, I know.  But I just discovered that my issue was pretty stupid, but I'll post it for completion:

I was neglecting to add  time() to the expires time on the cookie, so it was expiring immediately.

The expires time should be   time() + seconds